# Помогите разобраться в постановке "тире" в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Покинув в этот час министерство, он пожертвовал обедом в столовой, а дома никакой еды не было – кроме ломтя черного хлеба, который надо было поберечь до завтрашнего утра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь **тире в функции выделения**.

Справочник Лопатина, § 21:

> ...Тире ставится для подчеркивания, акцентирования поясняющих членов
> предложения, расположенных в конце предложения. Чаще всего это
> обстоятельство: *Это очень скверно, как я должен был писать — из-за
> куска хлеба*  (Бун.); *…И опять побрел по улице рикша — на этот раз к
> отелю*  (Бун.); *На другой день семинаристы снова схватились с
> кадетами — открыто, у Летнего сада*  (Кав.); *За всю весну Николай
> встретился с Овражним только раз — случайно, на улице*  (Шол.)

Comment: Здесь не совсем обычный случай. Тире в присоединительных конструкциях ставится обычно при отсутствии присоединительных союзов или их аналогов. Но тема  предлогов  "кроме, вместо, помимо и др. рассматривается отдельно, там примеров с тире вроде бы нет. Интересно, есть ли примеры в практической литературе.

Comment: @Sharon из Нацкорпуса: Проектов его я почему-то не помню ― кроме дипломного, как раз того самого, о котором «Пожар в Архитектурном» /  Какой в нем смысл ― кроме сценографического? / Оно закрывало почти всю область возможного ― кроме той части, где равновесие мира грозило сместиться. / Готовностью проявлять терпение и упорство, учиться, вместо того чтобы развлекаться, трудиться, вместо того чтобы гулять, терпеливо выстраивать карьеру и беречь репутацию ― вместо того чтобы хапнуть и убежать. / Были и другие причины для визита ― помимо искренней благости тона Безлетова.

Comment: Да, впечатляет. Можно ориентироваться на практику.

Comment: спасибо большое :)